# Good way to remove something from a bathroom sink overflow drain?

Tags: drain, sink

My wife dropped an earring down the overflow drain of her bathroom sink.  The earring is about 1" in diameter, so the hole which goes from the overflow to the main drain is too small for it to pass through.

The earring is silver, so it's non-magnetic (I checked the other one to make sure).

Short of removing the sink and turning it upside-down, any other ideas on getting that thing out? I thought of just a hook and wire, but it would be a crapshoot on being able to hook it.

Just want to add, here's what the sink looks like. Note that the overflow drain is very narrow, and if you measured between the opening and the back of it, it's maybe 5/8":

[image]

Comment: How far in did it go?

Comment: It had dropped all the way down as far as I could tell. It was a freak thing, she dropped the earring, it hit the sink, and bounced INTO the overflow drain!

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I'd be going at it with a strongest vacuum you can come up with. Maybe put a nylon stocking over the end of the hose so the earring doesn't get damaged flying down the pipe.

Comment: Boom, worked great! I didn't have the patience to put the stocking over the end, but it took only about 10 seconds once I emptied the shopvac out. Great idea!

Comment: Make sure to run the sink for a few seconds after doing this, as some vacuums are strong enough to pull the water out, and if this water is gone, it will allow sewer gasses to enter your house

Comment: Good point. For clarity, Ferrybig is talking about the [drain trap](https://www.thespruce.com/the-purpose-of-a-drain-trap-2718770), not the sink itself.

Comment: Depending on your vaccuum, there's a chance it will suck water into the mechanism.  Ideally use a wet-capable machine, not your normal house carpet vacuum cleaner.

Answer (score 15):

If you absolutely, positively, *must* know for certain that you've hooked the earring, the whole earring, and nothing but the earring, then you want an endoscope:

[image: an endoscope]

An inexpensive USB or WiFi endoscope with attachments costs somewhere around $10 US. All you need to do is connect the endoscope to a phone or a laptop and use it like a webcam. Using the hook attachment, snake the camera into the drain until you see the ring, then hook the ring and pull it out. It could also be used in conjunction with other hooks, grabbers, or even a vacuum.

Comment: lol, there's no way that makes it down into the overflow trap.

Comment: Depending on how the trap is connected to the main sink drain, you might be able to push the endoscope in from below, then fish for the ring from above with a wire hook.

Answer (score 11):

You could try a flexible claw pickup.  Press the end, the claws open, let go and they close:

[image]

Comment: I don't believe that would fit into the overflow hole, or be able to make the bend down, but thx for the idea.

Answer (score 5):

A crapshoot might be your best shot. Try getting a few pipe cleaners and bend a  hook on the ends and go fishing. They are flexible and won't wedge the earring further down the drain. Some light gauge wire, like bell wire, would probably work too.

Answer (score 3):

A simple and cheap solution is a [flexible drain unclog stick](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Cobra-Hair-Snake-Flexible-Stick-Drain-Opener/813639679) (there's no real accepted trade name). They have hooks or tabs on the sides to grip things in the drain and pull them back out. Most hardware and general purpose stores carry them.

Comment: I think that is designed to pull hairs out.  I'm not sure it would grip well enough to pull an earring out.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica The ones that are barbed could do the job easily enough